# How transfer file from pc to a virtual machine?

Tags: vmware, transfer, suse

I have installed Vmware on my PC to create a virtual Linux OS, SUSE. Now, I want to transfer my file, from pc to virtual machine Suse. How can i do? I have to transfer over 10 Gb so it isn't suggested connecting to network. And, at the moment, I haven't removable storage.
Thanks

Comment: would [this](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2041196) helps ?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use a Pendrive, which can be detected on both system and the virtual machine. I tried this option and it worked well for my purposes.

Comment: Thanks but I haven't now storage so capacious.